# 7th grade percentage question

Tags: recreational-mathematics, percentages

In the year $2010$, John's monthly salary was $\$3500$.
John's monthly salary in $2010$ was $25\%$ more than it was in $2009$.

Calculate his monthly salary in $2009$.

Many of us debated the answer should be $\$2800$ as year $2010$ should be taken as $125\%$.

However, the answer given by the 7th grade teacher is $\$2625$.

What's your view on this question?

Comment: You are correct. The teacher arrived at their answer by saying the 2009 salary is 25% less than the 2010 salary, which is wrong. If John's salary was \$2625 in 2009, and the 2010 salary was 25% more, John's 2010 salary will be $2625\times1.25 = \$3281.25$ which is obviously not correct.

Comment: An counter example was given by a friend. If An apple cost $1. An orange cost $1.25. We can say the orange costs 125% of the apple but we cannot say the apple costs 75% of the orange. In fact, the apple costs 80% of the orange.

Comment: @SoGeeky you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_{2009}$ be John's salary in $2009$ and $S_{2010}$ in salary in $2010$. What is given is that $$3500=S_{2010}=1.25 \times S_{2009}$$ So, dividing both sides by $1.25$ leads to $$ S_{2009}= \frac{3500}{1.25}=2800$$ and you are perfectly right.